# can we extend multiple classes in jsp page using export attribute

Tags: java, jsp, page-directives

We can define multiple attributes in a single page directive or we can have multiple page directives in a single JSP page. But can we extend multiple classes in any jsp page using extends attribute?

for eg:

```
<%@ page extends="Class1" %>
<%@ page extends="Class2" %>
```

Comment: Why are you using something like this? It would be better to not use scriptlets or any other business logic handler in JSP directly.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I'm not following this kind of code. I just wanted to know can we do it or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> extends   Specifies a superclass that the generated servlet must extend

This means that writing `<%@ page extends="Class1" %>` is kind of equivalent to

```
class MyClass extends Class1 {}
```

because JSP page is compiled to java class with similar name (depending on container).
Since java does not support multiple inheritance writing more than one JSP attribute `extends` must be illegal.

Comment: Thanks for your question that caused me to read about this JSP attribute that I have never used and even did not know that it exists.